# Trocar o filtro on click wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

seguinte, sou iniciante com wordpress e php, então estou tendo problemas com meu primeiro tema construído do zero, tenho uma div que vai servir como seletor no site, através dela quero filtrar o conteúdo que vai aparecer no the loop.

```
<div class="select">
        <div class="select-cima" id="recentes">
            <span>Mais Recentes</span>
            <div class="barra-recentes">
                <div class="seta"><img src="" alt="seta-cima"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="select-baixo populares sumir" id="populares">
            <span>Mais Populares</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ao clicar nesses IDs os filtros devem ser diferentes, o filtro para recentes funciona naturalmente assim que eu chamo os posts do meu post_type personalizado (através de WP_Query mudando o post_type), mas não estou conseguindo filtrar os populares e também não estou conseguindo fazer com que tenha essa mudança nos filtros que já coloquei no código.
Segue abaixo a ideia que tentei fazer funcionar, mas além de não ter filtrado a página, fez reload, o ideal seria não fazer o reload.

Tentativa:

```
<a href="?meta_key=wpb_post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC"><span>Mais Populares</span></a>
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Não fiz exatamente o que gostaria, mas criei uma nova página com outro filtro e usei um link para cada seletor... Foi a solução que encontrei